# My Android app does not show up on the devices android market, but does on the website

Tags: android

I submiited a app to the Android market.  It shows up on the website, buty not when I go to the android market on a android device.
My account shows it as published and I dont see any error messages.
- Ted

Comment: Good point, dumb quastion How do I accept a answer?

Comment: Just go to the Answer you like and hover your mouse to the left of the question and a blank check mark should appear. Click it and it will turn green meaning you have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then something (uses-feature) is filtering it out for the particular device. You can use [aapt](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) to see what your apk requires. Also i think the web market will show you everything but if you click to install something it will only let choose a compatible device to install to.

```
aapt dump badging application.apk
```

**Example output:**

```
package: name='com.example.android.btexample' versionCode='' versionName=''
uses-permission:'android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.bluetooth'
sdkVersion:'3'
targetSdkVersion:'5'
application: label='BT Example' icon='res/drawable/app_bt_ex.png'
launchable activity name='com.example.android.btexample.MyActivity'label='' icon=''
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
main
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '160'
```

So if your device doesn't have bluetooth or a touchscreen you wouldn't see this app.

Comment: With this, also be aware that some `<uses-permission>` elements also define implicit feature requirements unless `<uses-feature android:required="false">` is also included.

Comment: @erich true. the permissions will also add the feature as in the bluetooth in the example.

Comment: Hi,I still cant get my app to show up on the device. I was not able to get aapt to work, but at the store it has the requrments as android 2.0 or higher and permissions as this application requres no special permissions to run, i had a hard time getting it to run,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have features on your application and the device you use don't has these features and the market doesn't shows for it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are set some restrictionons in your manifest file (i.e. limt a minSdkVersion and/or some device features via uses-feature tag)?

They are checked then you are looking throught the market app and doesn't then you are viewing online version through the browser.